# Is there a free Diff tool reference I can use in my application?

Tags: c#, diff

I need to compare the difference between two Strings and show the difference.
Like the notepad++ compare plugin.

I checked out the http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

and it was exactly what I needed, but its copyrighted and may not be used.

I'm developing in C#

Comment: Since NP++ is open source I'm surprsed you haven't looked at it.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the [Longest Common Subsequence Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). The wiki page has pseudo code that you can start from if you want to write your own.

Shameless plug... I wrote about this previously here:
http://sethflowers.com/blog/basic-diff-with-a-generic-solution-to-the-longest-common-subsequence-problem/

You basically have one method that computes a difference matrix that contains information about what is different between the two strings or collections. You can then backtrack through the matrix to come up with your "pretty" output, showing the actual differences.